# Azure Database Sync Group transformations

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have on-prem a MSSQL DB (around 300 tables) with a windows client desktop application and we are moving this to a newly-to-be-developed web app in Azure and Azure MSSQL DB.
My first tests with Azure Database Sync Group is working pretty well, however; in the old DB we have some strange DB-schemas with keys, foreign keys, constraints etc.
The first one for me to address is the primary key.
Lets assume we have a CONTACT table with a primary key ID, int; this ID is NOT identity insert, but the actual ID is handed out by a "LAST-ID"-contact table. Yes, lovely.
This table is responsible for the actual id, and contains only 1 column; ID.
By creating a new record in the OLD table the new record contains the new ID from the last-table.
In our new DB we want to do this with Identity Insert.
For a migration I can turn off the identity insert and turn it on later again. But it seems that this option is not possible with Database Sync Group i.e. transformations or what so ever.

Anybody knows if a aditional parameter or transformation can by applied when doing a sync?

Comment: You won't be able to sync across such a schema change.  And I wouldn't try to use Database Sync for a migration.  Instead read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/sql-server-to-sql-database-guide

Comment: I was afraid for that answer. For the migration itself it will not be used, but for a feature wise transition we need to keep both DBs in sync. Any alternatives who can do this? Or will it be a self-programming to the top ;)